# QuickBooks API: Get Invoice and Invoice Line Items without using SELECT *

Tags: sql, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

If I use the following QBSQL query to get invoices from QuickBooks:

`SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE CustomerRef = '123'`

then I successfully get all invoices and line items for customer number '123'.

However, SELECT * seems like overkill and bad practice, so I tried getting all valid columns instead (from which I could systematically remove columns I don't need):

`SELECT Id, SyncToken, MetaData, CustomField, HasAttachment, DocNumber, TxnDate, DepartmentRef, CurrencyRef, ExchangeRate, PrivateNote, TxnStatus, LinkedTxn, Line, TxnTaxDetail, CustomerRef, CustomerMemo, BillAddr, ShipAddr, ClassRef, SalesTermRef, DueDate, ShipMethodRef, ShipDate, TrackingNum, TotalAmt, ApplyTaxAfterDiscount, PrintStatus, EmailStatus, BillEmail, Balance, PaymentType, CheckPayment, CreditCardPayment, DepositToAccountRef, Deposit, AllowIPNPayment FROM Invoice WHERE CustomerRef = '123'`

This longer query gets all invoices, but line items are not included with each invoice.

Does anyone know how I can get all invoices and line items for each invoice without using SELECT *?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: QBSQL might not at all be the same as (T)SQL on this. Are you sure it's really a bad thing to do?

Comment: Andrew, yes, SELECT * queries are performing much slower than queries where we explicitly retrieve specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `SELECT *, Line.* from Invoice`

You can try this using [ApiExplorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Invoice).

**Adding snapshot**
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Using `SELECT *, Line.* FROM Invoice` returns the same results as simply `SELECT * FROM Invoice`.  That's a good try though.

Comment: You're trying this call against QBD or QBO ? In QBO, I tried the following now - https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/688779980/query?query=select * from Invoice
It returned lines too. We don't get lines for QBD. For that we should use Line.*
Can you please give another try.
Thanks

Comment: I am using QBO.  Both `SELECT *` and `SELECT *, Line.*` return invoices and line items, which is great.  However, I am trying to determine if I can retrieve all invoices and line items WITHOUT using `SELECT *`.  I would prefer to explicitly state columns if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The following works
select Line from invoice

I spoke too soon. This doesn't return all rows.

Comment: Yeah, that's what's so strange.  Using `SELECT Line FROM Invoice` returns two blank line items without any useful line item data.